# BIN2HEX & HEX2BIN Convesion in PHP

Tags: php, binary, hex, type-conversion

I want to convert 48 bit binary number (in string format) to HEX (12 char long). And same thing in reverse manner.
E.g

- binary '000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000' into hex '00000000000'
- binary '111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111' into hex 'FFFFFFFFFFFF'
- hex 'FFFFFFFFFFFF' into binary '111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111'
- hex '00000000000' into binary '000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000'

Tried the default bin2hex(), dechex(bindec($binary)), etc.

I am a newbie so please explain in detail.

Answer (score 1):

`dechex(bindec($binary))` should have worked ok, but you don't say what the problem was.

Fundamentally though, the hex2bin is for encoding binary data, not a binary string. For simplicity's sake, you might want to stick to using the in-built [`base_convert`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.base-convert.php) function, e.g.

```
echo base_convert('FFFFFFFFFFFF', 16, 2);
// 111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111

echo base_convert('111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111', 2, 16);
// ffffffffffff
```

Note that for your "zero" examples, you'll just get back a single zero. There's no real concept of length with the number zero in any base system that I'm aware of.